# Color Entire Row Based on Cell Value

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to color an entire row if two cells in that row have the same value.

```
For i = 2 To LastRow
    If Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 4).Value <> Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 6).Value Then
        Cells(i, 1).EnitreRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 255
    ElseIf Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 4).Value = Worksheets("Request Results").Cells(i, 6).Value Then
        Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5296274
    End If
Next i
```

The loop goes into the else statement first and I get

> "Subscript out of range"

on

```
Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5296274
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

change ColorIndex to Color.

```
Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
```

Answer (score 13):

> Does anyone know what could be causing this error?

From the [MSDN help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296089(v=office.12).aspx#xlDiscoveringColorIndex_ColorIndexProperty) on the `ColorIndex` Property:

> The ColorIndex property can have valid integer arguments between 0 and
>   56 that generate color. However, you can assign decimal or string
>   values to the property without generating a run-time error. In these
>   instances, Excel tries to randomly apply a color that corresponds to
>   the argument value. However, setting the property to an integer value
>   outside the range of 0 to 56 causes the following error:
>
> Runtime Error '9': Subscript out of range

You can find the Color Palette with the valid indices on the same page:

[image]

Note that `ColorIndex` is different than `Color`, which uses the RGB specification and is more versatile. More info on `Color` vs `ColorIndex` [here](http://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba/colors.php).

I personally prefer using `Color` and the built-in [VBA Color Enumerations](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Application/TousestandardcolorsvbBlackvbRedvbGreenvbYellowvbBluevbMagentavbCyanorvbWhite.htm) `vbBlack, vbRed, vbGreen, vbYellow, vbBlue, vbMagenta, vbCyan`, and `vbWhite`. For most applications these are enough, but if more colors are necessary then [using a custom enumeration color is also possible](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=53791), and more elegant than looking up the RGB tables..

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I used something like this on a similar row highlighting problem.

```
For Each Rng in SomeRange.Columns(1).Cells
  Rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = 5296274
Next
```

Comment: Is there a way to set the color using hexadecimal rgb value? (e.g. `#FF3410`)

Comment: @DrunkenPoney see https://www.excel-pratique.com/en/vba_tricks/hexadecimal-color-function.php