# VBA Color row 1 if A1 is unequal to blank and so on

Tags: vba, excel, colors

I'm trying to loop through row 1 and color it based on if the cell is blank or not. For example if something is in A1 then colour it light gray, if something is in cell B1 color it the same. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not use conditional formatting- no code required

Comment: Agree with @tompreston. But if you need VBA, try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25000691/1726522). By the way, the link is the first result when googling "excel vba color row based on value".

Comment: Its part of a project that has macros already scripted, would be nice if I could add that in too so that it works seamlessly. I just don't have a clue how to do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @CMArg Yeah I looked at that and can't get it to work Lol. Thanks for the help though. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like that, if there is text in A1 of an activesheet :

```
Sub test()
Dim c As Integer
c = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(ActiveSheet.Range("A1"))
If c > 0 Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Interior.ColorIndex = 15
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, works great however it only colors A1, I was hoping that it would colour A1, B1 and so on if the cell is unequal to blank. Any ideas?

Comment: You can make the same test to B1, by replacing A1 by B1

Answer (score 0):

This will color the row green if the expression is true. You specify the color as RGB.

`=ColorRowIF(A1=B1, 1, 181, 0)`

Or in your case, `ISBLANK` in the condition.

`=ColorRowIF(ISBLANK(B2), 1, 181, 0)`

```
Public Function ColorRowIF(Condition As Boolean, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer) As String
    Dim row As Integer
    row = Application.Caller.row

    If Condition = True Then
        ActiveSheet.Evaluate "ColorRow(" & row & ", " & r & ", " & g & ", " & b & ")"
    Else
        'ws.Rows(r).Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

    ColorRowIF = Condition
End Function


Public Sub ColorRow(row As Integer, r As Integer, g As Integer, b As Integer)

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    ws.Rows(row).Interior.Color = RGB(r, g, b)

End Sub


Function IsDate(CellDate As Date) As Boolean
    If CellDate >= 1 And CellDate <= #12/31/2199# Then
    ' 1 is equal to January 1, 1900
        IsDate = True
    Else
        IsDate = False
        End If
End Function
```