# Color a column by searching a particular text in A:A

Tags: vba, excel

Assist me with a VBA to color column from A:G, by searching a specific text, say 'UK'in Column A
[image]

Comment: Use conditional formatting. 1) Select a cell, say A2 2) Create a new rule that uses a formula to determine the formatting 3) Rule is =$A5="UK" 4) Adjust the range of the rule to fit your table

Comment: Ok, but UK in A5 is not stable, This will change.

Comment: Use macro recorder to help generate code and then modify to fit your needs. When you have code with specific issue, post it for analysis.

Comment: Then use a cell reference in the rule instead of hard-coded "UK"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Code1 works on every sheet in the workbook but if you like for this to work for the active sheet then try Code2. For Code2 remember to write the correct sheets name. Hope it helps.

Here you can choose an index color: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25000926/7238313

Code1:

```
Sub rowhighlight()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim nlast As Long

For Each sht In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    sht.Select
    nlast = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For n = nlast To 2 Step -1
            If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "UK" Then
                sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                'different color number place here----------------^
            End If
        Next n
     Next sht
 End Sub
```

Code2:

```
Sub rowhighlight()
Dim nlast As Long

Sheets("sheetname").Activate
Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
nlast = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For n = nlast To 2 Step -1
        If sht.Cells(n, "A").Value = "UK" Then
            sht.Range("A" & n, "G" & n).Interior.ColorIndex = 37
            'different color number place here----------------^
        End If
    Next n
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

a very short and dirty and rude code is the following:

```
Sub ColorColumns()
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("A1", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Find(what:=Application.InputBox("Text to search:", , , , , , , 2), LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Resize(, 7).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. Remember to keep the sheet containing the table  active when running the code. Alternatively, you can specify the sheet explicitly when setting the ws variable.

```
Sub SelectivelyColorARowRed()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    lng_lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Dim k As Long

    For k = 2 To lng_lastrow
        If Trim(ws.Cells(k, 1).Value) = "UK" Then
        'you can also apply UCase if you want the search to be case-insensitive
        'like: If UCase(Trim(ws.Cells(k, 1).Value)) = UCase("Uk") Then
            ws.Range(Cells(k, 1), Cells(k, 7)).Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        End If
    Next k

End Sub
```