# Excel VBA code to highlight rows for a specific cell

Tags: excel, vba, cell, rows, highlight

I have created an spreadsheet with 3 sheets:

`Sheet1 - Search`
`Sheet2 - Add Data`
`Sheet3 - Database`

I want to create a button (Update) to highlight rows (green) for value of cell D4 Sheet1 and highlight rows in Sheet3 (in column 1 i have data which i need to insert in D4 to highlight).
I have created one button but everytime just highlight the last row from Sheet3

```
Private Sub MDAno_Click()
currentrow = Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

If Len(Range("D4")) <> 0 Then

Sheet3.Cells(currentrow, 498) = "Investigating"

End If

End Sub
```

I have a condition in Sheet3 (if i have "investigating" in column 498 highlight row).
Can somebody help me with this ? Thanks

Comment: Highlight column A on Sheet3 based on D4 value on Sheet1? If that's your requirement, what your code actually does?

Comment: Any reason why you would want to VBA? This can be done using conditional formatting.

Comment: I need a button because when ID number which is searched in cell D4 to mark as complete or under investigation. I know is possible with conditional formatting.

Comment: @sktneer My code just highlight the last row of Sheet3, i need to highlight ID from D4 in Sheet3 column A. Thanks

Comment: did you read this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000691/vba-color-entire-row-based-on-cell-value

Comment: Yes but no working.

Answer (score 0):

Though it can be achieved with a simple conditional formatting, here is what you are trying to achieve...

```
Private Sub MDAno_Click()
Dim lr As Long, i As Long
Dim ID
lr = Sheet3.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
ID = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value
If ID <> "" Then
    For i = 2 To lr
        If Sheet3.Range("A" & i) = ID Then
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 498) = "Investigating"
        Else
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 498) = ""
        End If
    Next i
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: it's working but with a problem, if i search different value on D4 before i pressed button, just highlight current value on Sheet3. The last value highlighted will be unhighlighted.

Comment: In that case remove the else condition which is Else
            Sheet3.Cells(i, 498) = ""

Comment: @George You're welcome! Glad it worked. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)